# A phrase that captures the concept of making oneself falsely appear to be guilty for purpose of discrediting another party

Tags: word-choice, phrases, phrase-requests, pejorative-language

Perhaps this is more of a trope, but I'm looking for a phrase or word in English that describes the situation where:

(a) "Party A" consciously performs actions that establish a false expectation of wrongdoing.

(b) Some antagonistic "Party B" leaps to the conclusion of wrongdoing due to [a].

(c) The lack of wrongdoing is revealed by "Party A" to some unbiased "Party C", and "Party A" improves its standing to an unbiased audience or benefits from reducing the perceived objectivity or fairness of "Party B".

Is there some phrase or common anecdotal reference used by English speakers to reference this sort of situation?

An example of this would be the following: Let Party A be Alice, and Party B be Bob.  Bob's dog is missing, and because of some bad history, Bob claims to the police that Alice killed his dog.  Alice then waits until she knows (but Bob does not) that Bob is observing her, and digs a hole in her backyard, then appears to throw something into the hole.  Bob runs to tell the police he saw Alice burying his dog, and the police dig in the location Bob specifies.  It turns out that Alice was simply planting tulips.  Bob is discredited as being paranoid and Alice gains sympathy.  To clarify, it's unknown whether or not Alice actually killed Bob's dog, but she knows that there is suspicion cast on her by Bob's claims.

Another example could be the following: Alice is in fierce competition with Bob at work, and Alice knows that Bob is talking to others to gain information about her activities.  So Alice pretends to be stealing Bob's idea for a proposal, mentions this around the office, and then submits a proposal having nothing to do with Bob's idea.  Bob, upon hearing the rumors, angrily confronts his superior about this, and is red-faced after being presented with a copy of the report.

What word or phrase describes the deceit Alice carried out as described above, to benefit her standing with the police at Bob's expense?

Comment: I can't quite parse your question.  Party A is revealing their alibi to Party C in hopes of having them explain it to Party B?

Comment: The plot to every episode of "Three's Company"?

Comment: @DavidM Let me write an example, just a moment.

Comment: @DavidM I have provided an example.

Comment: Why would an innocent person ever bury a sack of flour. This would increase my suspicion.

Comment: @Oldcat Better?  The flour is now a tulip.

Comment: @Oldcat I had to look up "Three's Company" but I think that show is about drama arising from unintentional actions or misunderstandings.  What I'm talking about is something a little more sinister?

Comment: A related (but more general than what you're looking for) phrase is: ["(a game of) cat and mouse"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_and_mouse), which means "a **contrived action** involving constant pursuit, **near captures**, and **repeated escapes**."

Comment: @dingo_dan Hmm, yes, though I'm thinking this is more cat vs. cat...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch YES, that is very close... and it also embarrasses the officer for having pulled the man over with only circumstantial evidence.  Is there a more technical term for this?

Comment: @ElliotFrisch - did you do that on purpose‽

Comment: @ElliotFrisch I know you meant to leave that link as a joke, but it is actually quite relevant.  The "designated decoy" sets up a false expectation of wrongdoing, and in turn, discredits his accuser for leaping to conclusions and using perhaps underhanded methods based on weak circumstantial evidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This reminds me of the Hitchcock thriller, [Gas light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaslight_%281944_film%29), where a husband twists and manipulates events in order to convince everyone, and his own wife, of her mental instability. Gregory plants false memories, tricks her into hearing noises which no one else in the household hears, so that he can commit his wife, Paula, to a mental institution whereupon he will be unhindered in his attempts to find Paula's murdered aunt's  collection of jewels, hidden somewhere in the aunt's home. The same home where they now both reside.

> A picture disappears from the walls of the house, and Gregory says
>   that Paula took it, but Paula has no recollection of having done so.
>   Paula also hears footsteps coming from above her, in the sealed attic,
>   and sees the gaslights dim and brighten for no apparent reason.
>   Gregory suggests that these are all figments of Paula's imagination.

The cunning plan, tricks, and devious double-handed manoeuvres employed by the husband, played by Charles Boyer, lead to the film enjoying a huge success at the box office. As a result a new expression was coined, that of **gaslighting**, the word [gaslight] was used to describe an attempt to destroy another's perception of reality. The term was further popularized in Victor Santoro's 1994 book Gaslighting: *How to Drive Your Enemies Crazy*, which outlines *legal* tactics  which the reader may adopt to his own advantage

**Gaslighting**

> Psychologist Martha Stout states that sociopaths frequently use
>   [gaslighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaslighting#Clinical_examples) tactics. Sociopaths consistently transgress social mores,
>   break laws, and exploit others, but are also typically charming and
>   convincing liars who consistently deny wrongdoing. Thus, some who have
>   been victimized by sociopaths may doubt their perceptions. Jacobson
>   and Gottman report that some physically abusive spouses may gaslight
>   their partners, even flatly denying that they have been violent.

Comment: This is the answer to the question.

Comment: Key here is the fact that the husband is manipulating not just his victim, but also an independent audience to believe that his wife is losing her perception of reality.  Likewise, an abuser, particularly a psychological abuser, would attempt to create deliberate misunderstandings such that his or her victim would be discredited for other (true) allegations.

Comment: @user69419 glad to have been of help :)

Comment: This is an excellent answer!  I wish I could give +2 just for mentioning Hitchcock.

Comment: @DavidM I'm sorry for switching the accepted answer on you... this was just extremely surprising and dead-on.

Comment: @user69419 Why are you sorry?  This is FAR superior to my answer!!!!

Answer (score 4):

It's not an exact fit, but Alice is acting as an [*agent provocateur*](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_provocateur).   An *agent provocateur* is someone (often a spy) who baits you into performing an illegal act for someone else's gain.

She is provoking Bob into making a false accusation for the purpose of making him look foolish.  You might also say she's baiting him into bearing false witness.  Both of these *may* be interpreted as crimes.  Hence, *agent provocateur*.

As I've said, it's not an exact fit. But, it can be applied.

If she were the Police, it would be called **entrapment**.

But again, both of these words (as generally understood) require that Bob has committed a crime in reporting her.

Comment: Could the illegal act be for the agent provocateur's gain?

Comment: Let me think for a little bit, I think this is what I'm looking for.  However, I'd like something that doesn't quite imply that Bob committed a crime or did something unethical, just something that undermines Bob because it makes him appear paranoid or irrationally biased against Alice?

Comment: Yes. It can be for personal gain, although agent seems to imply on someone else's behalf.

Comment: Yes, I don't think its possible to find a better word or phrase than the one you suggest.

Comment: So a more clear-cut example of an agent provocateur would be Javert during the fictionalized events of the June Revolution in Les Misérables?

Comment: Ummmmmm ... Sort of.  Javert when he infiltrates the revolutionaries is not attempting to incite them to crimes.  Rather he is an undercover policeman (who happens to be working off of a personal grudge).  That is less *agent provocateur* and more undercover agent.

Comment: You're right.  I rewatched the relevant section of Les Misérables, and its clear Javert is simply trying to keep a low profile.

Comment: @user69419 I'm sorry you watched that again. At least you've now atoned for all of your sins in this life and the next. The book was good. The musical nearly destroyed my innards (especially the Hugh Jackman/Russell Crowe version).

Comment: You didn't like the 1998 version with Geoffrey Rush as Javert?

Comment: @user69419 Yes, that was much better. Liam Neeson was also good in that.

Comment: Apologies, I suppose I led you to somewhat publicly assert that I was someone who would own and watch the (2012) version with Russell Crowe as Javert, which then allowed me the opportunity to post a comment here showing that I had better taste than that.

Comment: @user69419 Hahahahahahahaha. Perhaps you should give yourself a proper screen name, so you don't get accused of  trying to be like Jean Valjean.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of gaining control over someone by devious means (which this seems to be) is frequently described as *Machiavellian*. Indeed it is perhaps close to a modern interpretation of *Machiavelli*, as expounded in *The Prince*.

However as part of some historical research, I discovered that the philosophy of the 15th-century Florentine, had been interpreted quite differently in earlier centuries. What we understand today and that which I have described above is merely a 20th-century interpretation.

see Femia, Joseph V 'The many Faces of Machiavelli' in Boucher & Kelly *Political Thinkers from Socrates to the Present* (Oxford 2003)

Comment: I agree that the tactic is "Machiavellian", however, this is less about exerting control over an individual, and more about using certain underhanded means of discrediting an individual in front of a third party.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, you could say that Alice is *setting Bob up*.  (I believe the original idea is *setting him up for a fall* but you wouldn't usually say it in full.)

This doesn't imply the specific details you asked about, with third party C, but it does cover Alice tricking Bob by giving him a false perception of events so that he would act accordingly, to his own detriment and Alice's benefit.

You could also colloquially describe the situation as "a set-up", e.g. "Bob thought his proposal had been stolen and went to the boss, but it was a set-up."